# Typescript prevent exports from beeing available globally?

Tags: node.js, typescript, module, namespaces, export

imagine following typescript folder structure:

```
index.ts
login/
  --index.ts
  --util.ts
registration/
  --index.ts
  --util.ts
```

Is there any way to restrict the exports (namespaces) of the modules to inside the folders? So for example if both of those `util.ts` modules export a function named `navigate()`. I want to use the function in the sibling index.ts but want to prevent an accidential misuse in the sibling folder:

`login/index.ts` should only have access to `login/util` exports, not to `registration/util`.

Also, additionally it would be nice to controll which of these methods are available in `/index.ts`. So maybe I need `navigate()` in `login/index.ts` and therefore export it in `login/util.ts`, but want to prevent it from beeing used in `/index.ts`. Is this possible with module syntax?
This is an example made up, I currently use ts-node and a quite large e2e-tesing project which is written in ts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

You'll need to add a tsconfig.json file to each directory.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: I'll give that a shot, but thats seems really hacky/unofficial to me because those subfolders aren't standalone projects. The docs even say that a tsconfig.json is indicating a new project.